Salesforce Marketing Cloud SMS API Error: "Unable to find ShortCode for definition, countryCode may be required"
Body:
I'm working with the Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) API to create an SMS definition for transactional messages. Below is the API request I'm sending:
POST /messaging/v1/sms/definitions/ HTTP/1.1
Host: et_subdomain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "definitionKey": "Order_Confirmation",
    "name": "Order_Confirmation",
    "description": "Using SMS Transactional API",
    "content": {
        "message": "We received your order %%OrderNum%%, but it's not quite ready. When it's complete, you'll be notified via email with pickup instructions.\r\n\r\nText STOP to opt out"
    },
    "subscriptions": {
        "shortCode": "12345",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "keyword": "ORDER",
        "autoAddSubscriber": true,
        "updateSubscriber": true
    }
}

Error:
{
    "message": "MCMS_UTM_Runtime_ObjectNotFound: Unable to find ShortCode for definition:Order_Confirmation. countryCode may be required in order to find shortCode",
    "errorcode": 30003,
    "documentation": ""
}

I have confirmed that my short code is provisioned for the US in my account. I'm not sure what could be causing this issue, as I believe the short code and country code are correctly configured.
Questions:

Is there anything wrong with the API request structure that could be causing this error?
Could this issue be related to account-specific configuration of short codes?
Are there any additional settings or configurations required in Marketing Cloud to ensure that the short code works for transactional SMS?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_transactional_messaging_sms/createSMSSendDefinition.html

I found the issue! It turned out that I was using the wrong installed app settings while making the API request.
When triggering SMS definitions via the API, it's crucial to ensure that the installed app's configuration settings (API permissions and associated Business Unit) match the short code you're trying to use. In my case, the app I was using was either missing the correct permissions for sending SMS or was linked to the wrong Business Unit where the short code wasn't properly configured.
Solution:
I double-checked the app settings in Marketing Cloud's Installed Packages and ensured that I was using the correct app with the necessary permissions for SMS.
Once I updated the app and associated it with the proper Business Unit (where the short code is provisioned), the API request worked perfectly without any errors.
So, if you're facing the same error, I recommend checking the following:
Ensure your installed package has the correct permissions (e.g., "SMS: Send SMS" or "SMS: Create Definitions").
Verify that the app is linked to the correct Business Unit where the short code is set up and provisioned for the country you're targeting.
If necessary, update the app's permissions and configuration, then retry the API call.
